# Again JoinTable is not filled in many-to-many hibernate relation

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, join

|AA| many-to-many |BB| many-to-many |CC|

mapped with join tables became

|AA|--|AA_BB|--|BB|--|BB_CC|--|CC|

(I can't post images sorry, low reputation)

Edited:
Short question is
why if a Create a Aa element, Bb element, Cc element
add Cc to Bb collection, Bb to Aa collection
Save(Aa)
Works ok (AA_BB filled)?

But if I create a Bb element, Aa element, Cc element
Add Aa to Bb collection
Add Cc to Bb collection
Save(Bb)
(AA_BB **not** filled?)

BB_CC is always filled.

end edit

```
 CREATE TABLE BB_CC (
  BBIDBB number(10) NOT NULL, 
  CCIDCC number(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (BBIDBB, 
  CCIDCC));
CREATE TABLE AA_BB (
  AAIDAA number(10) NOT NULL, 
  BBIDBB number(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (AAIDAA, 
  BBIDBB));
CREATE TABLE CC (
  IDCC  number(10) NOT NULL, 
  DESCR varchar2(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (IDCC));
CREATE TABLE BB (
  IDBB  number(10) NOT NULL, 
  DESCR varchar2(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (IDBB));
CREATE TABLE AA (
  IDAA  number(10) NOT NULL, 
  DESCR varchar2(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (IDAA));
ALTER TABLE BB_CC ADD CONSTRAINT FKBB_CC976918 FOREIGN KEY (BBIDBB) REFERENCES BB (IDBB);
ALTER TABLE BB_CC ADD CONSTRAINT FKBB_CC529716 FOREIGN KEY (CCIDCC) REFERENCES CC (IDCC);
ALTER TABLE AA_BB ADD CONSTRAINT FKAA_BB470776 FOREIGN KEY (AAIDAA) REFERENCES AA (IDAA);
ALTER TABLE AA_BB ADD CONSTRAINT FKAA_BB23574 FOREIGN KEY (BBIDBB) REFERENCES BB (IDBB);
```

Hibernate Configuration File

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
<!--  ORACLE -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.1.8:1521:GEROS</property>
        <property name="connection.username">xxxx</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxx</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="it.erreeffe.erreeffe2.Aa"/>
        <mapping class="it.erreeffe.erreeffe2.Bb"/>
        <mapping class="it.erreeffe.erreeffe2.Cc"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the reversed jpa class from tables
Aa (Bb, Cc similar) some parts missing.

```
@Entity
public class Aa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="AA_IDAA_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_AA")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="AA_IDAA_GENERATOR")
    private long idaa;

    private String descr;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Bb
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
        name="AA_BB"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="AAIDAA")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="BBIDBB")
            }
        )
    private Set<Bb> bbs;
```

My tests, the first working and the second do not.

First:

```
Session session;
        SessionFactory sf_ORA = new Configuration().configure(
                "hibernate.cfg.ora.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        session = sf_ORA.openSession();

//A
        Aa a = new Aa();
        a.setDescr("A1");
        a.setBbs(new HashSet<Bb>());
        //B
        Bb b1 = new Bb();
        b1.setCcs(new HashSet<Cc>());
        Bb b2 =new Bb();
        b2.setCcs(new HashSet<Cc>());
        b1.setDescr("B1");
        b2.setDescr("B2");
        //C
        Cc c1 = new Cc();
        Cc c2 = new Cc();
        Cc c3 = new Cc();
        c1.setDescr("C1");
        c2.setDescr("C2");
        c3.setDescr("C3");
        //FILL B
        b1.getCcs().add(c1);
        b1.getCcs().add(c2);
        b2.getCcs().add(c2);
        b2.getCcs().add(c3);
        //FILL A
        a.getBbs().add(b1);
        a.getBbs().add(b2);

session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            session.save(a);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
```

This do the right job:
Hibernate creates for me all the needed statements:

```
Hibernate: insert into Aa (descr, idaa) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Bb (descr, idbb) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Cc (descr, idcc) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Cc (descr, idcc) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Bb (descr, idbb) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Cc (descr, idcc) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AA_BB (AAIDAA, BBIDBB) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AA_BB (AAIDAA, BBIDBB) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into BB_CC (BBIDBB, CCIDCC) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into BB_CC (BBIDBB, CCIDCC) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into BB_CC (BBIDBB, CCIDCC) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into BB_CC (BBIDBB, CCIDCC) values (?, ?)
```

The joined result query is right:

A1|B1|C1

A1|B1|C2

A1|B2|C2

A1|B2|C3

Second (Ta-dan Here it is the problem)
Read B1 from DB add new Aa (A2) to B1.Aas collection add a new Cc (c4) to B1.Ccs collection, update B1.

```
Bb b1=null;
        session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            Query qGetB1=session.createQuery("Select id from Bb where DESCR ='B1'" );
            long idB1=(Long) qGetB1.list().get(0);
            b1=(Bb) session.load(Bb.class, idB1);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw ex;
        }

        Aa a2 = new Aa();
        a2.setDescr("A2");
        Cc c4 = new Cc();
        c4.setDescr("C4");

        b1.getAas().add(a2);
        b1.getCcs().add(c4);


        session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            session.flush();
            session.saveOrUpdate(b1);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
```

Generate Hibernate's:

```
Hibernate: select bb0_.idbb as col_0_0_ from Bb bb0_ where DESCR='B1' //SEARCH B1 ID
Hibernate: select bb0_.idbb as idbb1_0_, bb0_.descr as descr1_0_ from Bb bb0_ where bb0_.idbb=? //GET B1
Hibernate: select aas0_.BBIDBB as BBIDBB1_1_, aas0_.AAIDAA as AAIDAA1_, aa1_.idaa as idaa0_0_, aa1_.descr as descr0_0_ from AA_BB aas0_, Aa aa1_ where aas0_.AAIDAA=aa1_.idaa and aas0_.BBIDBB=? GET B1.Aas
Hibernate: select ccs0_.BBIDBB as BBIDBB1_1_, ccs0_.CCIDCC as CCIDCC1_, cc1_.idcc as idcc2_0_, cc1_.descr as descr2_0_ from BB_CC ccs0_, Cc cc1_ where ccs0_.CCIDCC=cc1_.idcc and ccs0_.BBIDBB=? GET B1.Ccs
Hibernate: insert into Aa (descr, idaa) values (?, ?) //OK
Hibernate: insert into Cc (descr, idcc) values (?, ?) //OK
Hibernate: insert into BB_CC (BBIDBB, CCIDCC) values (?, ?) //OK


... What about AA_BB record???? //!!!!!!!!
```

Why the joinTable AA_BB is not filled?

Thank's all for the attention.
Regards,
Francesco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a bidirectional association, one side is the owner side (the side without the `mappedBy` attribute), and the other is the inverse side (the one with the `mappedBy` attribute).

Hibernate only considers the owner side to know if there is an association between two entities. So, if A is the owner side in the relation between A and B, you must add B instances to A's collection to make an association persistent. Adding A instances to B's collection has no effect.

In general, **you** are responsible for maintaining the coherence of the object graph, and thus **you** should make sure that the owner side (at least) is always updated.

Comment: Does anyone know where in the documentation this is stated?

Comment: Section 3.2.4 of the JPA specifications: "Bidirectional relationships between managed entities will be persisted based on references held by the owning side of the relationship. It is the developer’s responsibility to keep the in-memory references held on the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent with each other when they change. [...] It is particularly important to ensure that changes to the inverse side of a relationship result in appropriate updates on the owning side, so as to ensure the changes are not lost when they are synchronized to the database."